# How to use CLI tool with multiple OpenWhisk platform instances?

Tags: ibm-cloud, openwhisk, ibm-cloud-functions

Developing OpenWhisk applications, I'm often switching between a local instance of the platform for development & testing and IBM Cloud Functions for production.

The OpenWhisk CLI uses a configuration file (`~/.wskprops`) to store authorisation parameters for the current platform endpoint.

How can I use the CLI tool with different environments without having to manually update the configuration properties each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The OpenWhisk CLI supports overriding the [configuration file](https://github.com/apache/incubator-openwhisk/blob/master/docs/cli.md#setting-up-the-openwhisk-cli) location using an environment variable (`WSK_CONFIG_FILE`).

Store platform credentials in separate configuration files and use this environment parameter to choose the platform instance to target.

```
$ WSK_CONFIG_FILE=~/.wskprops-dev wsk action invoke ...
```

Comment: missing "=" between "WSK_CONFIG_FILE" and  "~/.wskprops-dev"